# PostThreadMessage & SendMessage

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have three questions.

**1.** Is this safe to use PostThreadMessage to CWinThread?

**2.** Is this safe to use SendMessage(Between two applications)?

The messages can to disappear?what is the disadvantage of SendMessage,PostThreadMessage?there is a maximum count that I can to send?

**3.** What is the best way to kill CWinThread?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this safe to use PostThreadMessage to CWinThread?

It's safe insofar the thread posting the message won't be harmed, in case the message isn't delivered, or picked up. Messages posted to a thread get lost, when the receiving thread is in a modal loop (e.g. displaying a modal dialog, navigating through a menu, or during resize operations).

> Is this safe to use SendMessage(Between two applications)?

This is generally not safe. If the target application fails to retrieve incoming messages, the sending application hangs, too. Use [SendMessageTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx) or [SendNotifyMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644953.aspx) instead.

The disadvantage of `SendMessage` is, that it can lead to [Message Deadlocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx#deadlocks). The disadvantage of `PostThreadMessage` is, that messages may get lost (see [Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/09/30/9901065.aspx)).

There is a maximum of 10,000 posted messages per message queue (see [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944.aspx)).

> What is the best way to kill CWinThread?

The best way to kill a `CWindThread` is to not kill a `CWinThread`. If you need a thread to terminate, use an [Event object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655.aspx) (or some other synchronization primitive) to signal the thread to terminate. This gives the thread a chance to perform cleanup, release global resources, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I can to "reset" the message queue to get again 10000 messages? if I use PostThreadMessage and the queue is full I got 'false' in the result of the call to the function?

Comment: There is no way to reset a message queue. If the queue's capacity is depleted, any attempt to call `PostThreadMessage` will fail (it will return `FALSE` in that case). The documentation for [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944.aspx) provides general guidelines: *"This limit should be sufficiently large. If your application exceeds the limit, it should be redesigned to avoid consuming so many system resources. To adjust this limit, modify the following registry key."*

Comment: I did a test, I sent to CWinThread 20000 messages (PostThreadMessage), after the 10090 ~  message it returned false but when I tried again to send it again received another 10090 messages and again...
So as soon as I pass the limit, getting false then can continue?
The limitation that the total messages 10000 or 10000 that will be jointly messages waiting for?

Comment: The limit is 10,000 messages in the queue **at one time**. Once the target thread starts dispatching/handling messages, it'll make room for other messages to be posted. You missed the important part though: *"**If your application exceeds the limit, it should be redesigned to avoid consuming so many system resources.**"*